# Layout switching with a variant in i3wm

Tags: keyboard-layout, i3-wm

I want to use a variant of `bd` layout called `probhat` along with the default `us` layout. So in my i3 config file I have the following lines as startup commands

```
exec --no-startup-id "setxkbmap -layout us, bd -variant probhat"
exec --no-startup-id "setxkbmap -option 'grp:rwin_toggle'"
```

But it doesn't work. I restarted in order for the new settings to take effect.
I found the variant name using this:

```
localectl list-x11-keymap-variants bd
```

I would like to use the right win key as the layout switcher shortcut. Would that be problematic since the default `$mod` key is also the <kbd>win</kbd> key?

Comment: Run this command: `setxkbmap -layout 'us,bd' -variant 'probhat' -option 'grp:rwin_toggle'` if it worked change your command in config file with this one : `exec --no-startup-id "setxkbmap -layout 'us,bd' -variant 'probhat' -option 'grp:rwin_toggle'"`

Comment: "Would that be problematic since the default $mod key is also the win key?" I guess it would ...

Comment: @Ravexina could you suggest me a common key binding that would not be conflicted with the i3 specific shortcuts? Because i3 makes heavy usage of keyboard shortcut...

Comment: I use `grp:alt_shift_toggle` (Alt+Shift) as my keybinding in OpenBox. It shouldn't make any trouble in i3wm too.

Comment: @Ravexina running the command did apply a bd layout, however not the variant :(

Comment: From a programmers perspective this portion sounds interesting to me: `setxkbmap -layout 'us,bd' -variant 'probhat'`. If we consider *layout* and *variant* as key-value pairs, then it stands to reason that there is no way to tell which layout should the variant `probhat` be applied to. Something like this: `setxkbmap -layout 'us,bd' -variant 'null, probhat'` should make more sense

Comment: You should just leave it empty there is no need for 'null' : `setxkbmap -layout 'us,bd' -variant ,probhat`

Comment: এখন ঠিক আছে (Translation: Now it's working!). Could you please post it as answer so I could mark the question as answered? Also, when you use `alt+shift` do you press them together or one at a time?

Comment: Press Alt, while you are holding it... press shift and leave them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setxkbmap` command should be something like:

```
setxkbmap -layout us, bd -variant ,probhat
```

so it knows that `probhat` is the variant of `bd` layout.

Also you should change they keybinding to get rid of conflict with i3wm's meta key, I suggest using: `grp:alt_shift_toggle` (Alt+Shift).

The final command:

```
setxkbmap -layout us, bd -variant ,probhat -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'
```